# Deleting (binary search) and iterating over synchronized list

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am using an ArrayList to store objects in order (each object has a unique ID in the form of an integer), and frequently need to remove objects from the list based on their ID. So I have decided that an Iterator is not the way to go as it linearly accesses the list as far as I understand, and considering the size and frequency of searching, this is not feasible.

The second thing to take note of is that this is a multi-threaded environment, where the list may be iterated over (in order) while another thread may want to alter the contents (remove or add). I tried using a synchronized approach, but found that the following situations are still causing a ConcurrentModificationException every now and then.

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

public synchronized void removeFromList(int index)
{
    list.remove(index);
}

public synchronized void addToList(Object o)
{
    list.add(o);
}

public synchronized int findByID(int ID)
{
    //search for item in list
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    synchronized(list)
    {
        for(Object o : list)
        {
            o.render(g);
        }
    }
}
```

The paint method is actually from Swing. My final implementation won't involve Swing, however it has been a useful testing environment. I will still be needing a multi-threaded solution for later implementations.

I'm not too sure if my understanding of synchronization is spot on, but I have been trying desperately for the last few days to piece it together. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may fix my immediate problem, or even better, a link to an in depth resource (the size of a small novel is great!) where I may really sink my teeth in Java concurrent programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the synchronization: You have `synchronized` methods and you
synchronize the list containing your objects. A `void synchronized method()` is equivalent to

```
void method() {
  synchronized(this) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

So you synchronize the outer class instance and *not* the inner `list` instance. I guess that is causing your exception.

Comment: Ah I was definitely unaware that that signature would result in synchronizing this, instead of the resource inside it. Thank you very much for that! I shall do some testing with the revised code and see if I still get the exception.

Comment: After the testing, I have been unable to get the ConcurrentModificationException to appear with the new code. Changing back to what I had however does bring the exception up, so thank you very much for the information, it did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a collection, ordered by ID, with fast access by ID, then a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is the best option.

If you also want concurrent access, where you can iterate the list while it is being updated, then a [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) is your best option.

This way, you don't need to synchronize anything.

Comment: Considering the way the list is used, the constant access that the ArrayList provides is ideal, should I be able to get the synchronization right. It would also be preferable to learn how to use synchronization properly, as it appears I have some fairly nasty knowledge gaps. Thanks for the suggestion though, much appreciated.